# Connecting to MySQL directly through flutter application

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, mobile-application

Can someone explain to me why you can't connect to a MySQL DB directly through dart from a security point of view?

Comment: That usually depends on your `security  policies`. Generally, If your dart app serving as a web server in the same machine or network, you can directly connect to database. But if your dart web server is on different machine or network, you should not connect to database directly. That's roughly the same thing with dart app client via flutter. cmiiw.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard guideline on whether to connect frontend directly to backend or not. It is just a design practice that has been widely accepted and evolved over many years.

Typical app structure consists of
FRONTEND -> SOME MIDDLE LAYER -> BACKEND

Where your middle layer handles all the interactions/processing with the database and the frontend uses this functionality with some sort of API structure. Having this layer is extremely helpful when the application goes to scale, it gives an added abstraction to the frontend.

It is not advisable to directly fuse your frontend(your flutter app), to the DB(MySQL) because any efficient hacker might use basic man-in-middle attack to know your DB structure/connections/queries(There are some pretty effective decompilers present out there), and alter your data and you might not even get to know what caused the data to update unless you've applied some checks on DB layer.

Also, your frontend logic needs to be more of end-user centric than to handle the data of the user. Any backend system(java, node, etc) gives you added functionality & freedom to parse and present the data from either side.

You can use the sqlite package available to store basic data, like your session tokens, your app configurations etc, but it is advisable to keep the main user data like the logins, etc in a separate place, or better yet, you can use the firebase plugin to store data in document structure in the cloud.